# linear algebra question.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

Let $x\in \mathbb{R^n}$ be a nonzero columns vector. Define $A=xx^T\in  M_n( \mathbb{R})  $. What is the necessary and suffcient condition for $I-2A$ to be an orthogonal matrix?

Should I use $AA^T=I$?

Answer (score 0):

First we notice that $A=A^T$. Then we have

$(I-2A)(I-2A)^T=(I-2A)^2=I-4A+4A^2$.

Hence:

$(I-2A)(I-2A)^T=I \iff A^2=A$.

Your turn !

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the answer given is $x^Tx=1$.

Comment: I wrote "your turn !". This means, that you should elaborate, that from $A^2=A$, we get $A=I$.

Comment: @Fred In general $A^2 = A$ does not imply $A=I$. Moreover, $x^T x = 1$ is not the statement that $A=I$. But here's a hint for the OP, $A^2 = (xx^T)(xx^T) = x (x^T x) x^T$...

Comment: @onamoonlessnight: I know that in general $A^2=A$ does not imply $A=I$. Above we have also some other properties of $A$..........

Comment: Even in the above case, $A$ can have determinant zero, take for example $x=(1,0)^T$.

Comment: OOOps, you are right ....